# How to iterate over mutable elements inside another mutable iteration over the same elements?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have an array of `Element`s and I want to iterate over it to do some stuff, then iterate over all `Element`s inside the loop to do something. There is a relation between elements so I want to iterate to all other elements to check something. The elements are mutable references for reasons. It's a bit broad, but I'm trying to be general (maybe I should not).

```
struct Element;

impl Element {
    fn do_something(&self, _e: &Element) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut elements = [Element, Element, Element, Element];

    for e in &mut elements {
        // Do stuff...

        for f in &mut elements {
            e.do_something(f);
        }
    }
}
```

As expected, I got this error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `elements` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:13:18
   |
10 |     for e in &mut elements {
   |              -------------
   |              |
   |              first mutable borrow occurs here
   |              first borrow later used here
...
13 |         for f in &mut elements {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I know it's [a normal behavior in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references), but what's the recommended way to avoid this error? Should I copy the elements first? Forget about loops and iterate in a different way? Learn about code design?

Is there a Rusty way to do this?

Comment: You can't do this with iterators. I'd just use index based iteration (`for i in 0..elements.len()`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use indexed iteration instead of iterating with iterators. Then, inside the inner loop, you can use `split_at_mut` to obtain two mutable references into the same slice.

```
for i in 0..elements.len() {
    for j in 0..elements.len() {
        let (e, f) = if i < j {
            // `i` is in the left half
            let (left, right) = elements.split_at_mut(j);
            (&mut left[i], &mut right[0])
        } else if i == j {
            // cannot obtain two mutable references to the
            // same element
            continue;
        } else {
            // `i` is in the right half
            let (left, right) = elements.split_at_mut(i);
            (&mut right[0], &mut left[j])
        };
        e.do_something(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution is subtly different from the OP's code, in the fact that `doSomething` will never be called with the same two values. The other answer describes why.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this, period. [The rules of references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references) state, emphasis mine:

> At any given time, you can have either **one mutable reference** or any number of immutable references

On the very first iteration, you are trying to get **two** mutable references to the first element in the array. This must be disallowed.

---

Your method doesn't require mutable references at all (`fn do_something(&self, e: &Element) {}`), so the simplest thing is to just switch to immutable iterators:

```
for e in &elements {
    for f in &elements {
        e.doSomething(f);
    }
}
```

If you truly do need to perform mutation inside the loop, you will also need to switch to [*interior mutability*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/). This shifts the enforcement of the rules from compile time to run time, so you will now get a panic when you try to get two mutable references to the same item at the same time:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Element;

impl Element {
    fn do_something(&mut self, _e: &mut Element) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut elements = [
        RefCell::new(Element),
        RefCell::new(Element),
        RefCell::new(Element),
        RefCell::new(Element),
    ];

    for e in &elements {
        for f in &elements {
            // Note that this will panic as both `e` and `f` 
            // are the same value to start with
            let mut e = e.borrow_mut();
            let mut f = f.borrow_mut();
            e.do_something(&mut f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _Your method doesn't require mutable references at all_
What if it's actually `fn doSomething(&mut self, e: &mut Element) {}` and mutates both e and f.

Comment: @Tuupertunut that's what *You cannot do this, period* refers to, as does the section about the rules of references. Rust disallows two mutable references to the same item.